# What is the problem on payment retry with Sylius?

Tags: sylius, payum, paybox

I have a problem while implementing the payment process on my client website, using the [SyliusPayboxBundle](https://github.com/sil-project/SyliusPayboxBundle):

1. I start the payment process: A new `sylius_payment` entry (calling **A**) is created with the state `new`
2. I enter wrong card informations: The previous `sylius_payment` entry **A** is marked as `cancelled` and a new one is created  (calling **B**) with the state `new`
3. I enter good card informations: The entry **B** is deleted instead of being marked as `completed` as it's done when I use good card information on the first try, so I only have the **A** which is `cancelled`

The default state machine is not override, I don't understand why this is happening and my order is blocked in an unstable state: Sylius allows a new payment attempt, but the bank block it because in reality the payment was validated on the second attempt.

In the Profiler, I see Doctrine queries.

On the first `/payment/notify` (the bad card number):

- the creation of the **B** entry
- the update of the `state` and `details` of the entry **A**

On the second  `/payment/notify` (the good card number):

- the deletion of the entry **B**
- the update of the `details` of the entry **A**, not the `state`

In the second call, I thought that entry **A** would not be changed and entry **B** would be updated with `completed` status. This is not the expected process?

Comment: At least it is not default behavior in Sylius with another payment gateways. I would try to search issue in SyliusPayboxBundle

Comment: I have progress on this. The deletion is in the SyliusPayboxBundle yes, but even if I remove it, the second call to `/payment/notify` will on update the `details` of entry **A** instead of updating `state` and `details` of entry **B** which remains as `new`